# modify numpy array element inside function

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, function, numpy

A simple function returns error :"'function' object does not support item assignment"
Can I fix that without making a Class?

```
import numpy as np
        def board(n):
           return ( np.ones((n,n)))

       def cdiag(brd,i,j,n):
           m = i
           l = i
           for k in range(j+1,n-1,1):
               m = m-1
               l = l+1
               if m >=0:
                     brd[m, k] = 0.

               if l < n:
                    brd[l,k]=0
          return

    myboard = board(8)
    print(myboard)
    cdiag(myboard, 0,4,8)
    print(myboard)
```

line : `brd[m, k] = 0` returns error:

```
TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Works fine! I couldn't reproduce the error. Could you try again?

Comment: Are you sure that the code that you show is *exactly* the same as the code that triggerd the error?  I suspect that you got that error by calling `cdiag(board, 0,4,8)` instead of `cdiag(myboard, 0,4,8)`.

Comment: This code works fine on my laptop

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Guys!!
Have retyped the thing and now it is working.
Still do not know what was wrong before